# Class member decoration for Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

When debugging C++ code in Visual Studio, mouseover over a variable shows its value. If the variable is a structure, its members are shown in a table. If the variable is a class with inheritance, the inherited members are grouped in a treeview, and it is all getting messy. Sometimes (e.g. with matrix objects in [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) library) one needs to open several tree nodes before even seeing any values.

However, mouseover over a STL container yields a nice clean view of the number of elements (which is not even a member variable) and their values in a list.

If I wanted to write my own container class, is there a way to somehow decorate its members (in the *source code*) for the debugger to display in a way that would be easier to read, or is this functionality hardcoded in VS IDE binaries?

I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730838%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but that requires modification of some of IDE files, which is not what I would prefer. I would like anyone running my code to be able to see the value preview as intended, without having to modify their VS files.

Comment: There seems to be a [newer way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx) than the one you linked, though it doesn't work in mixed mode. The short answer is that the debugger (like most of VS) is definitely extensible, but not trivially so (for C++, anyway).

Comment: Visual Studio _what_? There have been many versions.

Comment: @Cameron I see, this is also a file that is installed, at least this time it is only copied without having to modify existing files. It seems like what I want is not possible. Thanks for the link, though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit any version, I'm interested if it is at all possible. If it is supported in the latest / phased out in some old, it is also of interest to me.

Comment: What version are _you_ using?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm using 6.0, 2008, 2012 and 2013. That may seem outrageous, I'm using 2012 / 2013 mostly only for compatibility testing.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in VS2012, a new way to create native visualizers was introduced by way of *.natvis files.  These files are XML and can be added to the Visual Studio projects folder in My Documents directory.

This article describes how to solve your problem of cleaning up the deep nesting into a cleaner format: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx

Previous to VS2012, you either had to modify the cryptic autoexp.dat file in the Visual Studio installation directory, or write a custom AddIn.